Seams not seaming
Nooob alert, as I am tired and exhausted of this project that im making, and the deadline aproaches quick. Does anyone know why the subdiv mod doesnt register inner edges as sharp?
Means a lot! 

can you share blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Please make this a simple as possible for us? Indicate as clearly as you can: what you want, what you've got, and the difference.
